# Jquery if else statment for tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, tooltip

I have a tooltip that appears when you mouseover a link. I want the tooltip to stay if you hover over it (because there are links and such in it), or disappear if you mouse away from the link.
I tried a couple things, but haven't figured it out. This is my first time building anything serious with jQuery.

The stuff below is what is in the .hover() 'handlerOut' event.

```
if($(this.a).mouseout())
{
    if ($('.tip_container').hover()) {
        $('.tip_container').css('display', 'block');
        $('.tip_container').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.tip_container').remove(0);
    });
} else if ($('.tip_container').hover() == false && $(this.a).mouseoff() == true)
    {
        $('.tip_container').remove(0);
    }
}
>>"this.a" refers to the link<<
```

With this and the other things I've tried the tooltip doesn't disappear unless you mouse over the off of it. I also tried

```
else if (!$('.tip_container').hover() && $(this.a).mouseoff()) {
```

Is it possible to have multiple conditions?

The main idea of the code is that if you mouse off of the link "this.a" the tooltip will be removed by:

```
$('.tip_container').remove(0);
```

but if you mouse over the tooltip it will not be removed until you mouse off of the tooltip.

Comment: I think you need to [re-read the jQuery documentation about the "hover" method.](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: if ($('.tip_container_').hover()) {...}
does work, but when you add multiple events it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good nights rest and ignoring it for a while I figured out a solution. This is what I put in the hover handlerOut event.

```
 var timer;

 timer = setTimeout(function() {
           $('.tip_container').remove();
       }, 500);                     
           $( '.tip_container' ).hover(
       function() {
           clearTimeout(timer);
           $('.tip_container').css('display', 'block');
       }, function() {
           $('.tip_container').remove();
       }
    );
```

On the hover out of the link it will wait before executing the remove and if the mouse hovers over the tooltip it will clear the timer and set the tooltip to block to keep it displayed then on that hover out of the tooltip it will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a fiddle or anything to demonstrate?

Maybe something like

```
$(this, '.tip_container').hover(function () {
        $('.tip_container').show();
  }, function () {
        $('.tip_container').hide();
  }
);
```

Basically bind both the link and the tooltip elements to the hover method, which hides/shows the tooltip element on mouseenter/mouseleave. The link Pointy posted in comments is a good place to start

Comment: I can't make a fiddle easily because it is part of a chrome extension that I'm making that relies on the sites it modifies to work. Sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately nope. Thanks for the try though!

Comment: ah! I think I've misunderstood your example - edited my answer

Comment: I figured that's what you meant, but it didn't work.